# "for" loop in mongodb shell does not iterate

Tags: mongodb

any attempt to use a loop on the shell returns only the last value in the array

for example:

```
var myarray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
    db.mylogs.find({ logid: myarray[i]});
}
```

The result will only return value of logid which is the value of location `myarray[4]`

Comment: `find` function is actually working. Here is how you can check. `var op = db.mylogs.find({ "parent": myarray[i]});
 printjson(op.toArray());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to iterate the [**`find()`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method, just use the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** method:

```
var myarray = [1,2,3,4];
db.mylogs.find({ "logid": {"$in": myarray} });
```

---

To get the total counts for each logid in the array, you can use the aggregation framework with the following pipeline operation:

```
var myarray = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    pipeline = [
        { "$match": { "logid": { "$in": myarray } } },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$logid",
                "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }
        }
    ];

db.mylogs.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: thanks, i am actually trying to use count and the $in is accumulating all the results together:   db.mylogs.count().  to be more specific i am looking to get a count of all records with logid 1, follow by all records with logid 2 etc...

Comment: @goldtl You should not leave such salient details in your question. Please edit the question to include this.

Comment: I would like to add that the performance of `$in` queries gets worse the bigger the arrays are.

Comment: What if I want to use find in for loop ?